# ¿La fuente serif de CSS cambia depende al dispositivo?

Tags: html, css, web

Yo se que las fuentes(typograficas) `serif` son un tipo de fuentes. Ahora mi pregunta es en CSS cuando le pones  a un parrafo el tipo de fuente `font-family:  serif;` que fuente toma. Quisiera saber si esto cambia en diferentes dispositivos(ó SOs) o si en realidad la fuente serif tambien es una fuente, porque le puse la fuente solo `serif` a mi blog y quisiera saber si talvéz cambia o es la misma fuente en todos los dispositivos.

Comment: En teoría deberían ser igual para todos los SO pero si lo que querés es tener diferentes opciones, podés agregar una coma y especificar otra por si no existe. Por ejemplo: `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, serif;`, esto quiere decir que si no existe Roboto en tu pc o en el cliente, busca el siguiente.

Comment: Si claro eso lo sé, pero justamente no quiero utilizar otra fuente solo la `serif`,  ya que se supone que por que le pones al final siempre existirá. No quiero cargar otra fuente.

Comment: La fuente la leerá o de una URL o del sistema operativo del server, luego entonces si tu fuente existe en el server no hay mayor problema

Comment: cambia según el navegador, sistema operativo y dispositivo, por lo general se eligen estándares ["Any font that fits this typographic role may be used to represent the generic serif family."](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#valdef-font-family-serif) : cualquier fuente que encaje en el rol puede ser usada, (times sería el estandar serif, verdana el sans serif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La propiedad `font-family` es un grupo de fuentes, que puede contener
>   varios nombres de fuentes como un sistema "alternativo". Si el
>   navegador no admite la primera fuente, intenta con la siguiente
>   fuente.

Cuando no se establece de forma explícita el tipo de letra,o no se encuentran instaladas , los
 navegadores muestran el texto con un tipo de letra por defecto

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Dentro de la página http://www.fontfamily.io encontraras un formulario para ver información sobre distintas tipografías y como se mostrarían en Browsers/ diferentes S.O

Answer (score 0):

Como te han dicho en los comentarios las fuentes por defecto varian dependiendo del navegador (y a veces del SO), por ejemplo la "serif" de Firefox puede ser diferente a la que usa chrome.

Es recomendable que especifiques tu el tipo de letra para evitar estos detalles, o tambien podrias utilizar un "font stack", que se usa para definir varias fuentes para escoger, asi podrias poner la primera como la opcion preferida y en caso de no encontrarla, la segunda sera usada etc..

Esta pagina te puede servir de referencia: https://www.cssfontstack.com/

EDIT:

En chrome puedes revisarla en chrome://settings/fonts En Firefox en la configuracion--> idioma y apariencia --> En donde esta la fuente predeterminada hay un boton de "avanzadas" (opciones avanzadas) y ahi puedes revisar